# My music quiz just stops

Tags: python

it doesn't come up with a error, it just doesn't complete its while loop. A question is asked from the list and if the user inputs the correspoinging answer for the answer key, a point is scored

```
#Music Quiz
import random

print ("Welcome To the Maths Quiz")
name = input("Please enter your name : ")
neigh = input("Please enter your area : ")
#Questions and Answers
randomQuestions = { 1 :"What is Stormzy's new single?",
                    2 :"What is Lethal Bizzles's new single?",
                    3 :"Who sang Umberella?",
                    4 :"Who sang The Hills?",
                    5 :"Who featured with MNEK to sing Never Foget You?",
                    6 :"Who is married to Kim Kardashian?",
                    7 :"What is Kanye's first childs name?",
                    8 :"What date did Wiz Khalifa and A$AP Rocky perform at the o2?"}
#Defines the questions to the answers
qAns = { "What is Stormzy's new single?" : "WickedSkengMan4",
                    "What is Lethal Bizzles's new single?" : "Dude",
                    "Who sung Umberella?" : "Rihanna",
                    "Who sung The Hills?" : "The Weekend",
                    "Who featured with MNEK to sing Never Foget You?" : "Zara Larson",
                    "Who is married to Kim Kardashian?" : "Kanye West",
                    "What is Kanye's first childs name?" : "North West",
                    "What date did Wiz Khalifa and A$AP Rocky perform at the o2?" : "17/10/15"}
#askedqs is where the aske questions are stored so they cannot be `reasked`
askedqs = {}
#While statement  makes sure it can only happen 5 times
score = 0
x = 0
#While x is less than 5 means thatonly 5 times can it be looped before it         doesnt qualify and the code moves on
 while x < 5:
 #Choses the random question from the array by selecting a number out of the amount of questions
    rand1 = random.randint(1,8)
#If the randm number is in the list that stores the asked questions, it is redifined
    if rand1 in askedqs:
        randomNum = random.randint(1,8)
        while rand1 notin askedqs:
            rand1 = random.randint(1,8)
        print(randomQuestions[rand1])
        cQuestion = randomQuestions[rand1]
    userAnswer = input("")  
    if userAnswer.lower() == qAns[rand1].lower():
            print("Well done! \n")
            score +=1
    else:
         print("Wrong answer! ", qAns[cQuestion].lower(), "\n")
         askedQs[rand1] = cQuestion
         rand1 = random.randint(1,8)
    x = x + 1
 print ("Hello World")
```

Help on any other errors is also appriceated

Comment: Try debugging the issue with [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/pdb.html). If you learn to use debuggers, you'll easily solve this and future issues ;)

Comment: There are some oddities in the indentation; you may want to double check and [correct](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33703155/edit) those. The space in front of `while x < 5:` is one, and `in askedqs:` should likely be on the previous line; please check.

Comment: If it doesn't complete its while loop, at what point does it stop? Does it stop, or "hangs"?

Comment: This code has multiple syntax errors and wouldn't actually run. For example, `while rand1 not` and `in askedqs` on separate lines. What's up with that? It's really important that the code you post is the same as the code you ran; posting slightly-different code is like taking a sick kid's brother to the doctor for a diagnosis.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a great place to post full code snippets. We don't debug for you, but we can answer specific questions. Consider learning to use pdb (as stated above), and more about software debugging in general. Also, you should try to make your code as readable as possible before posting. For Python, that means complying with [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). (You may find there are formatting errors that are breaking your code.)

Comment: It never _enters_ the `while` loop: When `if rand1 in askedqs` is True then `while rand1 not in askedqs:` is False. However, that code isn't formatted properly: there's an indentation error on `while x < 5:` and as  user2357112 mentioned there shouldn't be a line break in the middle of `while rand1 not in askedqs:`

Comment: The problem is likely that the indentation of `x = x + 1` isn't correct but  since the posted code has several syntax and spacing problems I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed almost everything ;)

```
#Music Quiz
import random

print("Welcome To the Maths Quiz")

name = input("Please enter your name : ")
neigh = input("Please enter your area : ")

# list of Questions and Answers
data = [
    ("What is Stormzy's new single?", "WickedSkengMan4"),
    ("What is Lethal Bizzles's new single?", "Dude"),
    ("Who sung Umberella?", "Rihanna"),
    ("Who sung The Hills?", "The Weekend"),
    ("Who featured with MNEK to sing Never Foget You?", "Zara Larson"),
    ("Who is married to Kim Kardashian?", "Kanye West"),
    ("What is Kanye's first childs name?", "North West"),
    ("What date did Wiz Khalifa and A$AP Rocky perform at the o2?", "17/10/15")
]

# number of asked question
asked_number = []

score = 0

# repeat 5 times
for _ in range(5):

    rand = random.randint(0, len(data)-1)

    while rand in asked_number:
         rand = random.randint(0, len(data)-1)

    # get question and asnwer
    question, answer = data[rand]
    answer = answer.lower()

    print(question)
    user_answer = input("").lower()

    if user_answer == answer:
        print("Well done! \n")
        score +=1
    else:
        print("Wrong answer! ", answer, "\n")
        asked_number.append(rand)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change as little as possible while getting it working correctly. I also tried to avoid hardcoding the number of questions and redundancy such as having the questions defined twice as it can lead to errors later on:

```
#Music Quiz
import random

print ("Welcome To the Maths Quiz")
name = input("Please enter your name : ")
neigh = input("Please enter your area : ")

#Questions and Answers
qAns = [ ("What is Stormzy's new single?", "WickedSkengMan4"),
        ("What is Lethal Bizzles's new single?", "Dude"),
        ("Who sung Umberella?", "Rihanna"),
        ("Who sung The Hills?", "The Weekend"),
        ("Who featured with MNEK to sing Never Foget You?", "Zara Larson"),
        ("Who is married to Kim Kardashian?", "Kanye West"),
        ("What is Kanye's first childs name?", "North West"),
        ("What date did Wiz Khalifa and A$AP Rocky perform at the o2? (DD/MM/YY)", "17/10/15") ]

#askedqs is where the aske questions are stored so they cannot be `reasked`
askedqs = {}
score = 0

#only loop 5 times
for x in range(5):
    while True:
        #Choses the random question from the array by selecting a number out of the amount of questions
        rand = random.randint(0, len(qAns)-1)
        if rand not in askedqs:
            askedqs[rand] = True
            break
    question, answer = qAns[rand]
    print(question)
    userAnswer = input("")  
    if userAnswer.lower() == answer.lower():
        print("Well done! \n")
        score +=1
    else:
         print("Wrong answer! ", answer, "\n")

print("Quiz complete,", name, "of", neigh + ",", "your score was", score)
```

I also fixed what I think was an error in that you only added questions to the 'asked' list if they were answered incorrectly. That could have been an indentation error, whitespace is very important in Python.

I also think you might want to print something better at the end, and use the name and neighbourhood that you asked the user to provide.